# Is it known that Flinn, Hopwil and Narishma betrayed Rand by the end of The Path of Daggers?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

I just started reading Winter's Heart and I came across an odd passage, where Logain is told that there are new deserters that have to be hunted:

- Gedwyn
- Torval
- Rochaid
- Kisman
- Dashiva
- Flinn
- Hopwil
- Narishma

Although it is clear that the first 5 did betray Rand, it is not clear that Flinn and Narishma betrayed him. On the last chapter of The Path of Daggers the encounter of Flinn with Rand doesn't make clear that they also betrayed him. Should I just read and find out or did I miss something?

Comment: "Should I just read and find out" This is generally the best advise when reading any form of fiction :) I don't think you missed anything. Do you really want an answer including spoilers?

Comment: Pfft, I don't even remember Flinn, or Hopwil by now. As far as Jahar is concerned I was surprised you'd ask (no, he definitely didn't).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it known that Flinn, Hopwil and Narishma betrayed Rand by the end of The Path of Daggers?

No, this isn't known, you haven't missed anything. All of the mentioned characters were missing from the Black Tower and are labelled deserters.

Big spoiler:

> Mazrim Taim labelled those 3 deserters along with the rest, simply because he wanted them out of the way. Supposedly they questioned Taim's methods. Labelled traitors, they had to flee and find some way to protect themselves from getting hunted down. As for who is loyal and who is a Darkfriend, we can't really know until in the very last book of the series.